# Domain Driven Design (DDD) - Can Domain Services have remote procedure calls?

Tags: typescript, domain-driven-design

I am working on a DDD project and I have a UseCase(ApplicationService) that needs to deploy a project to Kubernetes. So, I have `DeployProjectUseCase` with inputs (projectId, databaseType) and it first needs to check the database type that the application uses in order to create the specific pods, secrets etc. It will invoke the external service of Kubernetes, but according with the type it has to use some specific methods from it. I thought that this logic shouldn't be in the useCase and be polluted, but instead use a DomainService that will dependency inject the external service. I don't know if Domain Services can have remote procedure calls, but I found this from Vaughn Vernon's book:

```
There are times when a Domain Service is concerned with remote invocations on
a foreign Bounded Context (2). Yet, the focus here is different in that the Domain
Service is not itself providing a remote procedure call interface but is rather the
client of the RPC.
```

So, I thought an implementation like this:

I have a Factory that returns the appropriate Domain Service according to the database type. The `DeployProjectUseCase` calls this and delegates the job to the domain service. I have created a `NetworkServicePort` and an adapter that uses Kubernetes library for Nodejs, in order to be injected in the useCase and then to the Domain Service:

**NetworkServicePort**

```
export interface NetworkServicePort {
  createSecret(namespace: string, body: TCreateSecretBody): Promise<void>;
  createStatefulSet(namespace: string, body: TCreateStatefulSetBody): Promise<void>;
  createConfigMap(...): Promise<void>;
  createPersistentVolume(...): Promise<void>;
  ...
}
```

**DeployProjectUseCase**

```
export class DeployProjectUseCase {
 constructor(
    private projectRepo: ProjectWriteRepoPort,
    private networkService: NetworkServicePort,
  ) {}
  
  async execute(requestDTO: DeployProjectRequestDTO): Promise<DeployProjectUseCaseResponse> {
    const projectFound = await this.projectRepo.getById(projectId);
    if (!projectFound) {
      return fail(...);
    }

    const domainNetworkService = DomainNetworkServiceFactory.createDomainNetworkService(requestDTO.databaseType, this.networkService);
    await domainNetworkService.deploy(projectFound);
    
    ...

    await this.projectRepo.update(projectFound);

    return ok();
  }
}
```

**DomainNetworkServiceFactory**

```
export interface DomainNetworkService {
  deploy(project: ProjectEntity): Promise<void>;
}

export class DomainNetworkServiceFactory {
  static createDomainNetworkService(
    type: string,
    networkService: NetworkServicePort,
  ): DomainNetworkService {
    switch (type) {
      case 'mongo': {
        return new MongoNetworkService(networkService);
      }
      case 'postgreSQL': {
        return new PostgreSQLNetworkService(networkService);
      }
      default: {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**MongoNetworkService**

```
export class MongoNetworkService implements DomainNetworkService {
  constructor(private networkService: NetworkServicePort) {}

  public async deploy(project: ProjectEntity): Promise<void> {
    // here have a mapper from Project aggregate to the DTO that service accepts
    await this.networkService.createNamespace(...);
    generatePassword(); // generate username and password from a library
    await this.networkService.createSecret(...);
    ...
    await this.networkService.createStatefulSet(...);
    ...
    const infraNetworkService = InfraNetworkServiceEntity.create({
      type: INFRA_NETWORK_SERVICE_TYPES.MONGO,
    });
    project.addInfraNetworkService(infraNetworkService);
  }
}
```

**PostgreSQLNetworkService**

```
export class PostgreSQLNetworkService implements DomainNetworkService {
  constructor(private networkService: NetworkServicePort) {}

  public async deploy(project: ProjectEntity): Promise<void> {
    // here have a mapper from Project aggregate to the DTO that service accepts
    await this.networkService.createNamespace(...);
    await this.networkService.createConfigMap(...);
    await this.networkService.createPersistentVolume(...);
    ...
    const infraNetworkService = InfraNetworkServiceEntity.create({
      type: INFRA_NETWORK_SERVICE_TYPES.POSTGRESQL,
    });
    project.addInfraNetworkService(infraNetworkService);
  }
}
```

It seems to me that the above has a domain logic that could be inside a Domain Service, but can a Domain Service have a remote procedure call? Otherwise, this logic could be inside the Application Service, but it seems wrong to me and it would be polluted. Does something like this make sense? How would you implement it with DDD? Any ideas would be really helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view MongoNetworkService, PostgreSQLNetworkService are neither domain nor application services. They are more like infrastructure services. That is why the design is fine. The only problem I can see here is the line

```
project.addInfraNetworkService(infraNetworkService)
```

I couldn't clearly understand if "project" in this line is your domain object if so this call  shouldn't be leaked to infrastructure service should be handled on layer above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes the project is a domain object. MongoNetworkService will also generate username and password that would probably be Value Objects and have some domain logic inside it, that's why I was wondering if it could be considered as a domain service.

Comment: Such a design could cause some headache in the long run depending on requirements. First of all you are passing a domain object as a parameter to these async methods and trying the update the state of that same object to save it later. If there is any other possible client which could update the same data in other use-case before your update that entity you may have a data consistency issue. Secondly though everybody has it is own understanding but I would say passing an aggregate as a parameter is not a wise idea for long term maintenance. I would rather do the other way around.

Comment: But isn't the Domain Service handling business logic and thus take as parameters aggregates, value objects etc?

Comment: As I said it is a matter of debate always but in my implementations domain services contain the business logic only if it spans several aggregates. In all the other cases domain ENTITY has the business logic and services (infrastructure) is provided as a parameter to the entity's method if required for the logic.